# What does it signify when Denna goes barefoot for miles?

Tags: character-motivation, costume, the-kingkiller-chronicle

In The *Wise Man's Fear*, in one scene, Kvothe meets Denna, and she walks with him for miles, barefoot, through the city (including on cobblestones) and the countryside.

Now when Kvothe has gone barefoot,

> first it was due to three years of dire poverty, then to losing his only pair of shoes in a fire,

then to the memory of his three years. Auri never wears shoes because she is mentally ill, and Elodin often doesn't wear them because he is highly eccentric. With Denna, does it signify/hint at anything about her past or her character? (A history of poverty? Free-spiritedness?)

Comment: I'd be hard pressed to put something together concrete, but this feels like one of many hints that Denna has just as many events and turns in her tale as Kvothe.

Comment: With this many people going barefoot, for this many reasons, maybe the question is what it signifies about the *author*.